# Excel graph legend doesn't match markers

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've formatted the markers of a chart using VBA:

```
Dim sc As SeriesCollection
Set sc = MySheet.ChartObjects("MyChart").Chart.SeriesCollection

Dim p As Point, s As Series
For Each s In sc
    For Each p In s.Points
        p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
        p.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = s.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
        p.MarkerSize = 3
    Next p
Next s
```

However, the markers in the chart area don't match up with the markers in the legend (the border colour is the same, but the fill colour in the legend is different). Note the colour inside the boxes on the right (the legend):

[image]

I've looked around at a few different properties of the Chart family, but can't find what controls this. The `Point` properties `MarkerBackgroundColor` and `MarkerForegroundColor` seemed likely, but don't fix it. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you reformat point by point, even if you reformat every point in the series, the series itself (and the legend) retains the original formatting. Rory's answer below shows the way to format the entire series at once. The point format properties are also available to the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you were looping the seriescollection, you could simply do all the markers in one go:

```
For Each s In sc
    s.MarkerBackgroundColor = s.Border.Color
    s.MarkerSize = 3
Next s
```

Comment: When the entire series is reformatted in this way, the legend symbols pick up the formatting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found with a bit more digging:

```
Worksheet.ChartObjects(Index).Chart.Item(Index).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB
```

Pretty lengthy!